# Index not used for date range condition

Tags: postgresql, index, range-types

I was querying like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM orders
WHERE planned_shipping_date >= '2022-04-04'
AND planned_shipping_date < '2022-04-05'
```

Then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335970/postgresql-query-between-date-ranges/48117316#48117316) and, because in more complicated queries it made the query easier to read, I rewrote the query like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM orders
WHERE planned_shipping_date <@ daterange('2022-04-04', '2022-04-05')
```

I believe they are semantically identical, but look at the plans:

```
Aggregate  (cost=76.91..76.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.066..1.068 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using orders_planned_shipping_date_idx on orders  (cost=0.29..69.73 rows=2872 width=0) (actual time=0.067..0.646 rows=2813 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((planned_shipping_date >= '2022-04-04'::date) AND (planned_shipping_date < '2022-04-05'::date))
        Heap Fetches: 0
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=2753.57..2753.58 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=18.309..18.311 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using orders_planned_shipping_date_idx on orders  (cost=0.29..2751.93 rows=655 width=0) (actual time=17.520..18.132 rows=2813 loops=1)
        Filter: (planned_shipping_date <@ '[2022-04-04,2022-04-05)'::daterange)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 128138
        Heap Fetches: 0
```

The use of the date range seems to preclude the use of an index.

Do I need a different index or should I just not use date ranges like this?

Comment: "I believe they are semantically identical" -- no, they are certainly not.

Comment: @mustaccio What makes you say that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your queries are semantically identical, but syntax matters too.

In order to be supported by an index, a `WHERE` condition has to look like this:

`<indexed expression> <operator> <constant>`

- `<indexed expression>` is what was used in `CREATE INDEX`
- `<operator>` is an operator from the operator class of the index
- `<constant>` has to be constant for the duration of the index scan (at least `STABLE`)

Additionally, PostgreSQL knows [support functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-optimization.html) that allow it to use index scans in certain other cases, but that does not apply here.

Your problem is the operator `<@`, which is not supported by B-tree indexes. As a consequence, PostgreSQL cannot use the index to check your condition. So keep using your original query.

To support `<@`, you'd need a GiST index.

Comment: Are there plans to implement support for `<@` operator by B-tree indexes? Or are there other indexes, which support `<@`?

Comment: Yes, there are GiST indexes.